# S3 - What Exactly Is A Prefix? And what Ratelimits apply?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I was wondering if anyone knew what exactly an s3 prefix was and how it interacts with amazon's [published s3 rate limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/request-rate-perf-considerations.html):

> Amazon S3 automatically scales to high request rates. For example,
>   your application can achieve at least 3,500 PUT/POST/DELETE and 5,500
>   GET requests per second per prefix in a bucket. There are no limits to
>   the number of prefixes in a bucket.

While that's really clear I'm not quite certain what a prefix is?

Does a prefix require a delimiter?

If we have a bucket where we store all files at the "root" level (completely flat, without any prefix/delimters) does that count as single "prefix" and is it subject to the rate limits posted above?

The way I'm interpreting [amazon's documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html#object-keys) suggests to me that this IS the case, and that the flat structure would be considered a single "prefix". (ie it would be subject to the published rate limits above)

> Suppose that your bucket (admin-created) has four objects with the
>   following object keys:
>
> Development/Projects1.xls
>
> Finance/statement1.pdf
>
> Private/taxdocument.pdf
>
> s3-dg.pdf
>
> The s3-dg.pdf key does not have a prefix, so its object appears
>   directly at the root level of the bucket. If you open the Development/
>   folder, you see the Projects.xlsx object in it.

**In the above example would s3-dg.pdf be subject to a different rate limit (5500 GET requests /second) than each of the other prefixes (Development/Finance/Private)?**

---

What's more confusing is I've read a couple of blogs about amazon using the first N bytes as a partition key and encouraging about using high cardinality prefixes, I'm just not sure how that interacts with a bucket with a "flat file structure".

Comment: for the key `s3-dg.pdf` the partition key would be `s3-dg.`, see my expanded answer below.

Comment: To add to the confusion, consider the following statement from the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/optimizing-performance-design-patterns.html): "Amazon S3 automatically scales in response to sustained new request rates, dynamically optimizing performance. While Amazon S3 is internally optimizing for a new request rate, you will receive HTTP 503 request responses temporarily until the optimization completes. After Amazon S3 internally optimizes performance for the new request rate, all requests are generally served without retries."

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You're right, the announcement seems to contradict itself. It's just not written properly, but the information is correct. In short:

1. Each prefix can achieve up to 3,500/5,500 requests per second, so for many purposes, the **assumption** is that you wouldn't need to use several prefixes.
2. Prefixes are considered to be the whole path (up to the last '/') of an object's location, and are no longer hashed only by the first 6-8 characters. Therefore it would be enough to just split the data between any two "folders" to achieve x2 max requests per second. (if requests are divided evenly between the two)

For reference, here is a response from AWS support to my clarification request:

> Hello Oren,
>
> Thank you for contacting AWS Support.
>
> I understand that you read AWS post on S3 request rate performance
>   being increased and you have additional questions regarding this
>   announcement.
>
> Before this upgrade, S3 supported 100 PUT/LIST/DELETE requests per
>   second and 300 GET requests per second. To achieve higher performance,
>   a random hash / prefix schema had to be implemented. Since last year
>   the request rate limits increased to 3,500 PUT/POST/DELETE and 5,500
>   GET requests per second. This increase is often enough for
>   applications to mitigate 503 SlowDown errors without having to
>   randomize prefixes.
>
> However, if the new limits are not sufficient, prefixes would need to
>   be used. A prefix has no fixed number of characters. It is any string
>   between a bucket name and an object name, for example:
>
> - bucket/folder1/sub1/file
> - bucket/folder1/sub2/file
> - bucket/1/file
> - bucket/2/file
>
> Prefixes of the object 'file' would be:  `/folder1/sub1/` ,
>   `/folder1/sub2/`, `/1/`, `/2/`. In this example, if you spread reads
>   across all four prefixes evenly, you can achieve 22,000 requests per
>   second.

Comment: Can anybody provide a complete code snippet that reliably achieves more than 3,500 PUT/POST/DELETE and more than 5,500 GET requests per second on a single bucket by taking advantage of prefixes? I have tried for a long time now and haven't managed.

Comment: For SES S3 Actions, the "Object Key Prefix" needs to not have a leading slash: `folder1/sub1/`

Comment: This seems to contradict with [the presenter for STG343](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=54AhwfME6wI) who says slashes are treated like any other character and partitioning is automatic.

Comment: Contradicted in [official AWS documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-prefix-nested-folders-difference/).

Comment: @Chris I'd gladly update the answer with new info, but that link sounds just as vague as the rest of the other AWS communications on the topic (if not worse). - "The folder structure *might not necessarily* indicate what is considered a partitioned prefix to support request rates". The support answer I posted verbatim is as close as I got to a solid response.

Comment: It looks like AWS support gave you incorrect information, or out of date information. All the official docs that give any definition for a prefix contradict this answer.

Comment: A prefix is not related to '/'. A prefix can be any length starting from the first character of a key. And the length is dynamically determined and changed by AWS itself to adjust the number of partitions to accommodate the usage rate. See https://youtu.be/rHeTn9pHNKo?t=3219

Answer (score 18):

S3 prefixes used to be determined by the first 6-8 characters;

This has changed mid-2018 - see announcement
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/07/amazon-s3-announces-increased-request-rate-performance/

**But that is half-truth**. Actually prefixes (in old definition) still matter.

S3 is not a traditional “storage” - each directory/filename is a separate object in a key/value object store. And also the data has to be partitioned/ sharded to scale to quadzillion of objects. So yes this new sharding is kinda of “automatic”, but not really if you created a new process that writes to it with crazy parallelism to different subdirectories. Before the S3 learns from the new access pattern, you may run into S3 throttling before it reshards/ repartitions data accordingly.

Learning new access patterns takes time. Repartitioning of the data takes time.

Things did improve in mid-2018 (~10x throughput-wise for a new bucket with no statistics), but it's still not what it could be if data is partitioned properly. Although to be fair, this may not be applied to you if you don't have a ton of data, or pattern how you access data is not hugely parallel (e.g. running a Hadoop/Spark cluster on many Tbs of data in S3 with hundreds+ of tasks accessing same bucket in parallel).

**TLDR**:

"Old prefixes" still do matter.
Write data to root of your bucket, and first-level directory there will determine "prefix" (make it random for example)

"New prefixes" do work, but not initially. It takes time to accommodate to load.

PS. Another approach - you can reach out to your AWS TAM (if you have one) and ask them to pre-partition a new S3 bucket if you expect a ton of data to be flooding it soon.

Comment: Where is the information regarding old prefixes still relevant coming from? Experience? Just to understand. I'm having problems with the "new" changes, throttling requests, but I need more info before refactoring all the system.

Comment: @MicheleGargiulo, yes experience working with our customers.

Comment: We've just gone through a detailed investigation, directly liaising with the internal S3 teams. As of March 2022, this is the only correct answer. AWS are aware that their documentation is incorrect/misleading; hopefully they'll get round to fixing it at some point.

Answer (score 15):

This looks like it is obscurely addressed in an amazon release communication

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/07/amazon-s3-announces-increased-request-rate-performance/

> Performance scales per prefix, so you can use as many prefixes as you
>   need in parallel to achieve the required throughput. There are no
>   limits to the number of prefixes.
>
> This S3 request rate performance increase removes any previous
>   guidance to randomize object prefixes to achieve faster performance.
>   That means you can now use logical or sequential naming patterns in S3
>   object naming without any performance implications. This improvement
>   is now available in all AWS Regions. For more information, visit the
>   Amazon S3 Developer Guide.

Comment: that only raises more questions! lol.  those statements seem contrary.  that quote seems to be saying the limit depends on prefix, but prefix no longer matters...? but the limit still applies to prefix. but the prefix no longer matters (guessing they hash internally to get a real partition?). :confused:

Comment: @CoryMawhorter If you get to the bottom of this (or did), could you let us know. I will do the same.

Comment: @Lo-Tan will do. i'm just going to play ostrich myself and assume it truly is unlimited, at least for my purposes/throughput.

Comment: I think by prefix, you should now just read 'folder' even though folders aren't technically a thing in a bucket. I think the note about randomising was because before prefixes were based on the first 8 characters of the bucket key whereas now they are based on the full 'folder' path.

Comment: This does not answer what is a prefix.

Comment: Just to give an example, I scanned CloudTrail S3 bucket using Athena. It is highly partitioned, with pretty long keys (e.g. AWSLogs/<account>/CloudTrail/region/2022/03/04/<account>_CloudTrail_ap-northeast-1_20220304T0020Z_weotiruy.json.gz) and I got rate limit when queried for the last year. It scanned thousands of folders and files. My assumption it will be OK because of thousands of prefixes. But it seems that it was all considered a single prefix because of static prefix part of about 50 characters.

Answer (score 6):

In order for AWS to handle billions of requests per second, they need to shard up the data so it can optimise throughput. To do this they split the data into partitions based on the first 6 to 8 characters of the object key. Remember S3 is not a hierarchical filesystem, it is only a key-value store, though the key is often used like a file path for organising data, prefix + filename.

Now this is not an issue if you expect less than 100 requests per second, but if you have serious requirements over that then you need to think about naming.

For maximum parallel throughput you should consider how your data is consumed and use the most varying characters at the beginning of your key, or even generate 8 random character for the first 8 characters of the key.

e.g. assuming first 6 characters define the partition:

`files/user/bob` would be **bad** as all the objects would be on one partition `files/`.

`2018-09-21/files/bob` would be **almost as bad** if only todays data is being read from partition `2018-0`. But **slightly better** if the objects are read from past years.

`bob/users/files` would be **pretty good** if different users are likely to be using the data at the same time from partition `bob/us`. But not so good if Bob is by far the busiest user.

`3B6EA902/files/users/bob` would be **best** for performance but more challenging to reference, where the first part is a random string, this would be pretty evenly spread.

Depending on your data, you need to think of any one point in time, who is reading what, and make sure that the keys start with enough variation to partition appropriately.

---

For your example, lets assume the partition is taken from the first 6 characters of the key:

for the key `Development/Projects1.xls` the partition key would be `Develo`

for the key `Finance/statement1.pdf` the partition key would be `Financ`

for the key `Private/taxdocument.pdf` the partition key would be `Privat`

for the key `s3-dg.pdf` the partition key would be `s3-dg.`

Comment: awesome! thank you, i'm still confused about how the rate limits apply to the distributed system necessity of choosing a shard key in order to replicate and distribute data.  Ie even though we know that s3 is choosing a partition key (in terms of distributed systems, based on the first 6-8) chars of a prefix, does a "flat" bucket with no "prefix" still fall under the posted rate limits? (sorry if this is not clear)

Comment: The prefix is really only the bit of the key that comes before the filename. In reality it is the whole key that is used to form the partition structure.

Comment: `3,500 PUT/POST/DELETE and 5,500 GET requests per second per prefix` refers to partitions. You don't know for sure how many partitions are created for your data, but by varying the first few characters enough you can get maximum request throughput.

Comment: @MattD We are getting rate limited and thought the whole key was used to partition. I just don't think that is true based on what I am seeing in our system.

Comment: @Lo-Tan, that was my understanding too, the AWS Exams make a big deal out of achieving performance based on partitioning using the first 6 or 8 characters. The announcement referenced in the other answer does not seem to be clear, and removed the ability for the developer to optimise.

Comment: This guide is obsolete. It does not matter if you put a random prefix or not now because S3 will now hash that internally:

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/07/amazon-s3-announces-increased-request-rate-performance/ 
"This S3 request rate performance increase removes any previous guidance to randomize object prefixes to achieve faster performance. That means you can now use logical or sequential naming patterns in S3 object naming without any performance implications. "

Comment: We are not sure what that announcement means, it is contradictory... "Performance scales per prefix, so you can use as many prefixes as you need in parallel to achieve the required throughput."        and       "This S3 request rate performance increase removes any previous guidance to randomize object prefixes to achieve faster performance.". So how do you add more prefixes? Looking for practical experience.

Comment: As I understand it means that full path (without file name) is the "prefix", so we should try to not use the same prefix:  /bob/users - but rather /bob/users/21rlkfjrijRandom/file.jpg

Answer (score 5):

The upvoted answer on this was a bit misleading for me. 
If these are the paths

bucket/folder1/sub1/file
bucket/folder1/sub2/file
bucket/1/file
bucket/2/file

Your prefix for file would actually be
folder1/sub1/
folder1/sub2/
1/file
2/file

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingKeysHierarchy.html
Please se docs. I had issues with the leading '/' when trying to list keys with the airflow s3hook.

Comment: I don't think the last two paths in your example should have `/file` at the end.

Comment: I think this answer is misreading the linked doc. It says that `A prefix can be any length` and is chosen by the user. See my answer for more info.

Answer (score 2):

In the case you query S3 using Athena, EMR/Hive or Redshift Spectrum increasing the number of prefixes could mean adding more partitions (as the partititon id is part of the prefix). If using datetime as (one of) your partititon keys the number of partittions (and prefixes) will automatically grow as new data is added over time and the total max S3 GETs per second grow as well.

Answer (score 2):

> S3 - What Exactly Is A Prefix?

S3 recently updated their document to better reflect this.

"A prefix is a string of characters at the beginning of the object key name. A prefix can be any length, subject to the maximum length of the object key name (1,024 bytes). "

From - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-prefixes.html

Note:  "You can use another character as a delimiter. There is nothing unique about the slash (/) character, but it is a very common prefix delimiter."

As long as two objects have different prefixes, s3 will provide the documented throughput over time.

Update: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/glos-chap.html#keyprefix reflecting the updated definition.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the accepted answer is misunderstanding the official docs.

According to [this official doc](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/s3-prefix-nested-folders-difference), a prefix is not a statically defined thing but ***can be any length***. For example, if a bucket is structured as `BucketName/Project/WordFiles/123.txt` then `BucketName/Project/WordFiles/`, `BucketName/Project/WordFiles/1`, and `BucketName/Project/WordFiles/12` are all valid prefixes one may choose to scan!

So, if using `boto3` then `s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket='bucket', Prefix='foo', ...)` would be subject to 5,500 requests per second.

What I can't figure out:

- are the S3 rate limits global, per machine, or per connection?
- what about `s3_client.get_object()`? The [official API docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/client/get_object.html#) don't even mention prefixes anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

A video was released by AWS Support:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xfy5UC4fXy8

indicating:

```
resource: s3://BucketName/Project/WordFiles/123.txt
  prefix: BucketName/Project/WordFiles/
```

This video put out by AWS a month ago, indicates:

```
resource: s3://BucketName/Project/WordFiles/123.txt
  prefix: /Project/WordFiles/
```

I think it doesn't make a difference if the BucketName is included in the "prefix".  It's safe to reason about prefix as "everything leading up to the last `/`"

Answer (score 0):

A prefix is not related to '/'. A prefix can be any length starting from the first character of a key. And the length is dynamically determined and changed by AWS itself to adjust the number of partitions to accommodate the usage rate. See https://youtu.be/rHeTn9pHNKo?t=3219