# What is definition of Amazon S3 prefix

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

What exactly is the definition of S3 prefix.

Lets say I have the following S3 structure:

```
photos/2006/January/sample.jpg

photos/2006/February/sample2.jpg

photos/2006/February/sample3.jpg

photos/2006/February/sample4.jpg
```

what will be the prefix for sample.jpg?

Either `photos` will be the prefix or the whole path till `sample.jpg` will be the prefix (i.e `photos/2006/January/`)

Because there is read write limit for each prefix.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [S3 - What Exactly Is A Prefix? And what Ratelimits apply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52443839/s3-what-exactly-is-a-prefix-and-what-ratelimits-apply)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

S3 is just an object store, mapping a 'key' to an 'object'.  In your case, I see four objects (likely images) with their own keys that are trying to imitate a filesystem's folder structure.

`Prefix` is referring to any string that would be a prefix to an object's key.

`photos/2006/January/sample.jpg` is just a key, so any of the following (and more) can be a prefix that would match this key:

- pho
- photos
- photos/2
- photos/2006/January/sample.jp
- photos/2006/January/sample.jpg

Note that the first three prefixes listed above will be a match for the other keys you mention in your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of a prefix as a path to a folder. Although they are not really folders, AWS has created prefix's to make it easier for us to visualize our data.

The prefix path is relative to the object. So for sample.jpg, the prefix is: `photos/2006/January/` but if i have a sample2.jpg inside `photos/2006/` then the prefix is the latter.