# How can I programmatically reduce/control S3 request rate?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How can I programmatically reduce/control S3 request rate?

```
Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Please reduce your request rate. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 503; Error Code: SlowDown; Request ID: TZJYPCC02W0YJFNC; S3 Extended Request ID: uEBpUJSvQ6t9+3rxq7BY70xYPWQeQBltI7BYcEzg9Wb8/rWuENBSaxG5CxyGJBzF+luhvcldIELSITu74/2HNw==; Proxy: null), S3 Extended Request ID: uEBpUJSvQ6t9+3rxq7BY70xYPWQeQBltI7BYcEzg9Wb8/rWuENBSaxG5CxyGJBzF+luhvcldIELSITu74/2HNw==
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1819)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleServiceErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1403)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1372)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1145)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:802)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:744)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:704)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:550)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:530)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5437)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5384)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.access$300(AmazonS3Client.java:421)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client$PutObjectStrategy.invokeServiceCall(AmazonS3Client.java:6508)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.uploadObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1856)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1816)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:3982)
    ...
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachTask.compute(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: It's great that you are contributing your findings to the StackOverflow audience, but could you please add more details of the problem you experienced? For example, what was the specific error (rather than having to hunt for it in the dump) and what were you doing to generate the error? Also, please explain how your solution fixes the problem rather than just showing a whole lot of code. This will help future readers. Thank you!

Comment: The error is AmazonS3Exception which asks to reduce request rate. I've reproduced it by for processing parallel stream on a batch of input which caused heavy request rate on S3. Solution is to programmatically reduce/control request rate to S3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to create a proxy which would incapsulate the logic to limit the rate.

Usage:

```
AmazonS3 s3 = ...build();
return rateFriendlyProxy(s3);
```

Implementation:

```
import static java.lang.Math.max;
import static java.lang.Math.min;
import static java.lang.System.nanoTime;
import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;
import static java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance;
import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS;
import static java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos;
import static org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.containsAny;
import static org.apache.commons.lang3.exception.ExceptionUtils.getRootCauseMessage;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

/**
 * This proxy implements dynamic request rate to S3 to deal with 'slow down' rejects<br>
 *
 * @see <a href="https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/07/amazon-s3-announces-increased-request-rate-performance/">Amazon S3 Announces Increased
 *      Request Rate Performance</a>
 * @see <a href="https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/http-5xx-errors-s3/">Configure your application to gradually increase request rates</a>
 * @see <a href="https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/optimizing-performance.html">Best practices design patterns: optimizing Amazon S3
 *      performance</a>
 */
public class AmazonS3RateFriendlyProxy implements InvocationHandler {

    private static final int MAX_RATE = 3_000_000;
    private static final int MIN_RATE = 100;
    private static final int MAX_RETRY_COUNT = 300;
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AmazonS3RateFriendlyProxy.class);

    public static final AmazonS3 rateFriendlyProxy(AmazonS3 s3) {
        return (AmazonS3) newProxyInstance(
                s3.getClass().getClassLoader(),
                new Class[] { AmazonS3.class },
                new AmazonS3RateFriendlyProxy(s3));
    }

    private AmazonS3 s3;
    private ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock(true);
    private AtomicLong leapTime = new AtomicLong();
    private AtomicInteger rate = new AtomicInteger(MAX_RATE);

    private AmazonS3RateFriendlyProxy(AmazonS3 s3) {
        this.s3 = s3;
    }

    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        for (int retryCount = 0;; retryCount++) {
            int rateSnapshot = rate.get();
            limitRate(rateSnapshot, leapTime, lock);
            try {

                return method.invoke(s3, args);

            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                String msg = getRootCauseMessage(e);
                if (!containsAny(msg, "Please reduce your request rate", "Please try again") || retryCount > MAX_RETRY_COUNT)
                    throw e.getCause();
                logger.warn("Rejected retry {}, at rate {}, {}", retryCount, rateSnapshot, msg);
                rate.compareAndSet(rateSnapshot, max(rateSnapshot / 2, MIN_RATE));
                sleep(SECONDS.toMillis(1));
            } finally {
                rate.compareAndSet(rateSnapshot, min(rateSnapshot + 1, MAX_RATE));
            }
        }
    }

    public static void limitRate(int rate, AtomicLong leapTime, ReentrantLock rateLock) {
        long targetLeapTime = 1_000_000_000 / rate;
        rateLock.lock();
        try {
            long timeSnapshot = nanoTime();
            long parkTime = targetLeapTime - (timeSnapshot - leapTime.get());
            if (parkTime > 0) {

                if (parkTime > 1_000_000)
                    parkNanos(parkTime);
                else
                    while (timeSnapshot + parkTime > nanoTime())
                        /* busy wait */;

                leapTime.set(timeSnapshot + parkTime);
            } else {
                leapTime.set(timeSnapshot);
            }
        } finally {
            rateLock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Or alternatively, you (1) reduce the concurrency of the fork-join threadpool that's controlling task list generation, or (2) invoke your for-each stream operation on a threadpool with limited concurrency.

Comment: Tried, this is bad option as for files of different sizes a request rate (start of a put or copy operation) will wave. And you will always be under the rate S3 can potentially cope with having a constant risk of breaking the limit when you encounter a batch of small files.