# How scalable is AWS Static Website hosting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, web-hosting

I am planning to host a static website (HTML, css) on AWS, with S3, route 53 and CloudFront. I was wondering if there could be any potential with scaling issues, if there was, for example, 100k concurrent requests to be on the site. Based on that is there any recommendations you would have?

Thanks for the advice!!

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of concurrency. What kind of app are you running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static website hosting is both resilient and redundant assuming it is configured correctly.

S3 is by default distributed across all availability zones within the region with your code covered by a resilient storage layer.

You are limited to [5500 get requests](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-request-limit-avoid-throttling/) from S3 per second **per prefix**.

For this reason you should take advantage of CloudFront to cache any assets that can be cached at the edge. At this point you will benefit from significant performance updates as the website will be cached locally to the user.

CloudFront supports 250,000 requests per second for each distribution with a total of 150 GBPs, as seen in the [quotas](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cloudfront-limits.html#limits-web-distributions). To benefit from this, also ensure your cache headers are appropriately set, enabling cached objects (such as CSS and JS) to be stored locally on the users device.

Route 53 is very resilient (and just like CloudFront benefits from [AWS Shield](https://aws.amazon.com/shield/) to protect against DDOS attacks). For your end user (and cost savings) you should ensure your TTL values are set to appropriate values to avoid over utilising lookups for DNS records.

Comment: "You are limited to 5500 get requests from S3 per second." this is not true. It's the rate that s3 can handle *per prefix*.

Comment: Thanks @jellycsc updated answer to make more clear

Comment: What does "per prefix" mean? sorry am very new to this!

Comment: @bobschwartz See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52443839/s3-what-exactly-is-a-prefix-and-what-ratelimits-apply

Comment: The prefix is the entire object key up to last / in the path so if your key is folder/subfolder/test.txt the prefix is folder/subfolder

Comment: No problem glad I could help